# Does Robocopy keep a log file by default?

Tags: robocopy

I copied a huge number of files using Robocopy, and received a note at the end that two files failed. I didn't set a switch to save a log file.

Is there a log file saved in a default location automatically? I'd obviously prefer not to re-copy everything, to get this information.

Answer (score 5):

Robocopy does not keep a default log file. It does however only copy files with differences by default. So if you tried the same copy again it would skip the ones that had already successfully copied.

Comment: How does it determine if something has changed?

Comment: "By default Robocopy will only copy a file if the source and destination have different time stamps or different file sizes."

Answer (score 3):

Use the V switch when running robocopy

> /V : Produce Verbose output log, showing skipped files.

You may also want to include this switch

> /FP :  Include Full Pathname of files in the output

[More robocopy command line options](http://www.computerhope.com/robocopy.htm)

Answer (score 3):

One thing you may find useful is to try the copy again with the `/L` switch. That switch is similar to the `-n/--dry-run` switches in rsync - it generates a log of what would happen but doesn't actually copy anything. It's nice because it's much quicker, non-destructive, and can be quite versatile when combined with other switches like `/V`, `/LOG:file` and `/LOG+:file`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want robocopy to create a log, you have to specify a log file with the `/log:[filepath]` parameter. I usually pair this with the `/tee` switch, so I see progress on the console as well.